# Vuejs custom plugin getelementbyid does not work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to create a vuejs plugin of the following codepen

https://codepen.io/hakimel/pen/nLFDv?editors=0010

Everything works fine if I dont change the line

```
var canvas = document.body.appendChild( document.createElement( 'canvas' ) );
```

but if I try to use the following line

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas')
```

it always returns

```
chart.js?28d6:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
```

I believe this happens because the div#mycanvas does not exist at this certain moment. But whats the work around of this?

this is my chart.js

```
export default {
    install: function(Vue) {
        Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, 'linechart', { value: new LineChart({ data: [] }) });
    }
}
```

and then I use the following code in the vue-component

```
created(){
            this.linechart.populate([
                { label: 'One', value: 0 },
                { label: 'Two', value: 100 },
                { label: 'Three', value: 200 },
                { label: 'Four', value: 840 },
                { label: 'Five', value: 620 },
                { label: 'Six', value: 500 },
                { label: 'Seven', value: 600 },
                { label: 'Eight', value: 1100 },
                { label: 'Nine', value: 800 },
                { label: 'Ten', value: 900 },
                { label: 'Eleven', value: 1200, future: true },
                { label: 'Twelve', value: 1400, future: true }
            ]);

            this.linechart.start();
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you add `<div id="canvas"></div>` to HTML DOM?

Comment: I just typed it out

Comment: Do you have a pen to share? Might be a couple of problems. First though is that the plugin runs way before your Vue application is initialised